# Enable PAM configuration (limits.conf) for a running daemon

Tags: daemon, docker, limits, pam

I'm currently attempting to develop a sandbox using Docker. Docker spawns process through a running daemon, and I am having a great deal of trouble enabling the limits set forth in the limits.conf file such that they apply to the daemon. Specifically, I am running a forkbomb such that the daemon is the process that spawns all the new processes. The nproc limitation I placed on the user making this call doesn't seemed to get applied and I for the life of me can not figure out how to make it work. I'm quiet positive it will be as simple as adding the correct file to /etc/pam.d/, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 2):

The PAM limits only apply to processes playing nice with PAM. By default, when you start a shell in a container, it won't have anything to do with PAM, and setting limits through PAM just won't work.

Here are some other ways to make it happen!

1. Instead of starting your process immediately, you can start a tiny wrapper script, which will do the appropriate `ulimit` calls before executing your process.
2. If you want an interactive shell, you can run `login -f <username>` (e.g. `login -f root`); that will use the normal login process to auto-log you on the machine (and that should go through the normal PAM mechanisms).
3. If you want *all* containers to be subject to those limits, you can set the limits on your system, then restart Docker with those lower limits; containers are created by Docker, and by default, they will inherit those limits as well.

Comment: Docker 1.6 (soon to be released), will allow setting per-container ulimits. More information and partial documentation can be found in the pull-request; https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9437/files