# pam limits in docker containers aren't working

Tags: docker

I added something in `/etc/security/limits.conf` in a docker container to limit the max number of user processes for `user1`, but when I run bash in the container under the user `user1`, `ulimit -a` doesn't reflect that limits defined in the pam limits file (`/etc/security/limits.conf`).

How can I get this to work?

I've also added the line `session required pam_limits.so` to `/etc/pam.d/common-session`, so that's not the problem.

I start the docker container with something like `sudo docker run --user=user1 --rm=true <container-name> bash`

Also, `sudo docker run ... --user=user1 ... cmd` doesn't apply the pam limits, but `sudo docker run ... --user=root ... su user1 -c 'cmd'` does

Comment: Have you seen [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979137/enable-pam-configuration-limits-conf-for-a-running-daemon), does it help here?

Comment: Hmm, I guess that does clarify a few things. Using `su user1 -c 'cmd'` is essentially the same thing as using a wrapper that sets all the ulimits I guess. That might be my best option here. Thanks!

Comment: Docker 1.6 (soon to be released), will allow setting per-container ulimits. More information and partial documentation can be found in the pull-request; https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9437/files

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/security/limits.conf` is just a file that is read by PAM infrastructure on boot.  Docker containers are clones of the kernel in pristine state after it just started.  This means that none of the inherited initializations of the environment will apply to container.  You have to use the 'limit' command directly to set the process limits.

Better way to do that would be to use container limits,  unfortunately current version of docker [doesn't support](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-cpu-and-memory) limits on number of processes.  Looks like the support will be coming in version 1.6 when it comes out, as @thaJeztah has mentioned.