# Limit number of processes started inside docker container

Tags: docker, pam

I'm trying to minimize damage made by fork bombs inside of a docker container.

I'm using `pam_limits` and `/etc/security/limits.conf` file is

```
1000:1128 hard nproc 40
1000:1128 soft nproc 40
```

This means that any user with id in range [1000..1128] can have up to 40 processes. This works fine if I run forkbomb in shell by user with such id.

But when I run fork bomb inside a docker container these limits are not being applied, so when I run command

```
# docker run -u 1000 ubuntu bash -c ":() { : | : & }; :; while [[ true ]]; do sleep 1; done"
```

I have as much processes as possible and all these processes belong to user with id=1000.

What's wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable PAM configuration (limits.conf) for a running daemon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979137/enable-pam-configuration-limits-conf-for-a-running-daemon)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When running a container, there is an option to limit the number of pids:

> `--pids-limit`:    Tune container pids limit (set -1 for unlimited)

The command would be:

```
docker container run --pids-limit 100 your-image
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options

Answer (score 1):

Not related with PAM, but you can limit the Docker container with "docker create" command, for example [Enduro/X](https://github.com/endurox-dev/endurox-docker) project uses some IPC queue limits, but in the same way you may set some other ulimit settings, as with number of processes it will be "-ulimit nproc=256:512", i.e soft limit and hard limit.

So for example:

```
$ sudo docker create --name bankapp-inst -it \
  --sysctl fs.mqueue.msg_max=10000 \
  --sysctl fs.mqueue.msgsize_max=1049600 \
  --sysctl fs.mqueue.queues_max=10000 \
  --ulimit msgqueue=-1 \
  --ulimit nproc=256:512 \
  bankapp
```

So after nproc setting, no more than 256 processes can be spawned, and if ulimit changed, then upper limit is 512 processes. Hope this helps!

Comment: Nproc is not a per container limit: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container---ulimit